# Install system.img on Android Phone

Tags: custom-roms, installation, htc

I have made some modification in the android source codes recompile sources and now I have ***system.img***, but I don't know how I can install that image on Android Phone. Have anybody do something similar ? Can anybody provide me some links or information how I can do that ? I am using HTC Amaze Phone.

Comment: Are you working from HTC's source or the AOSP?  The latter is highly unlikely to boot, or work in general if it does boot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a fastboot-enabled bootloader then it should be pretty simple. Just put the system.img file somewhere on your PC, connect your device via a USB cable, reboot into your bootloader's fastboot mode and then:

```
fastboot flash system /path/to/system.img
```

If you don't have fastboot then you'll have to jump through some more hoops. One option would be to use something like [unyaffs](http://code.google.com/p/unyaffs/) to extract the contents of the system.img (if it's an ext2/3/4 filesystem then just mount it) and then package it up as a zip file that can be installed from a custom recovery. There are [some tutorials floating around](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=936175) that explain the syntax of the installer script file, but the easiest way to figure it out would probably be to download a custom ROM for your device, unzip it, and look at the updater-script file (should be `META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` in the archive).

You may also be able to get away with simply using `dd` on the device, though I'd be careful if you decide to try it, and make sure you're booted into recovery:

```
adb push system.img /sdcard/
adb shell
dd if=/sdcard/system.img of=/your/system/partition
```

---

Alternatively, you can often build the source so that it creates a zip file instead of raw images, then install the zip from recovery. I'd suggest checking to see see if you have something like `make otapackage` available to you.

Comment: ♦ I have run `fastboot flash system /path/to/system.img` command and it successful install system.img on my phone HTC Amaze but when I try to switch it on, only HTC screen come up and my phone do not turn on :((( Can you help me.

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: There's a lot of reasons that could be happening, unfortunately. Where did you get the source code from? If it isn't from HTC then you may be missing necessary proprietary drivers to get the device to boot.

Comment: ♦ no I get that sources from Android official site http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: You're probably missing drivers, then, among other things. You could start with a porting guide ([like this one](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/bring_up.html)) and then work forward from there to see what exactly is failing, but there could be a variety of things that are causing problems.

Comment: and can you provide me some information how I can backup my phone ?

Comment: or where can I find working system.img and patch it again to repair my phone.

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: The best method is probably to grab a custom recovery image (like [ClockworkMod](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager)) and flash it from fastboot: `fastboot flash recovery /path/to/recovery.img`. Then you can use that to make a backup and/or flash a ROM of your choice. Flashing a new ROM should get your device into a bootable state, and you can get ROMs [from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1319&order=desc).

Comment: Okay and what do you mean saying grab ? I just  download custom mod from http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/device/ruby/developer/xboarder56?manifest=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.clockworkmod.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fxboarder56%2Fmanifest&name=Xboarder56&deviceName=HTC%20Amaze but it is .zip file.

Comment: how I must grab >

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: Download the appropriate recovery image for your device. There are links for a bunch of different devices on the page I linked to. Then boot into that recovery image, copy the zip file onto your phone, and use the recovery to install the zip file.

Comment: You should probably mention that your `system.img` partition can be found using the `recovery.fstab` or `vold.fstab` files. Or you can call `mount /system && df -h && umount /system` if you don't know where the fstab file is.

Comment: So, as far as i read, from your comments i understand something else. You have an HTC Amaze, that you are trying to flash a system.img file compiled from the AOSP branch. that is not possible. Your phone is a HTC phone so you need to compile it with their sources. You will never be able to flash the system.img of an AOSP rom, without flashing the entire partition list. You may want to read more about Cyanogen and TWRP. For now, you need to find the RUU file for your device, which will allow you to flash the system as it was. Not sure if data will be kept.